# Running a shell application (Universal G-Code sender) on Start-up - Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, shell, cron, raspberry-pi

Im trying to have the program Universal G-code sender load on start up but no matter what tutorial I look at it dosent work. When looking at its properties, its a shell script and the pathway for it is:

/home/fifex/Desktop/ugsplatform-pi/bin/ugsplatform

I have tried using python, and using the on boot procedures but nothing happend.

Comment: Try creating a systemd service.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `@reboot shell-command arg arg arg` in your [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

Use the [crontab utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) to edit your crontab, to put in the command line you want to run, preceded by [@reboot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab).

```
crontab -e
```

lets you edit the crontab. Keep in mind that the command won't have a usable current working directory when it runs, so give full pathnames.

Comment: so on crontab -e I put the code line:

@reboot sh /home/fifex/Desktop/ugsplatform-pi/bin/ugsplatform   

But unfortunately It didn't load on reboot